# Create Explorer.exe's File - Context Menu in WxPython application

Tags: python, user-interface, windows-xp, wxpython

I have a WxPython app that, among other things, has a integrated file-browser.

I want to be able to create a system-default file context menu (e.g. what you get if you right-click on a file in windows explorer) when a user right clicks on one of the items within my application.

Note: I already know how to create my own context menu (e.g. wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK), I want the *Windows* context menu.

To clarify, I do not want, or need to modify the existing system context menu, I want to be able to **display** it for a specific file within my application.

Basically, I know what was right clicked on, and where the mouse pointer is (if it's needed). I want to create the system context menu there, just like it works in windows explorer.

Comment: You could try and find out how Explorer++ does this (note: it is written in C++).

Answer (score 0):

If you have python win32 installed, then look under the directory `<PYTHON>/lib/site-packages/win32comext/shell/demos/servers`.  This contains a file `context_menu.py` which has sample code for creating a shell extension.

Update: I think you want the `folder_view.py` sample.

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I don't want to modify the system context menu, I want to **display** it *within* **my** application.

Comment: Does this correspond to the `SHCreateDefaultContextMenu` API in win32?  If so, I think you want `folder_view.py`.  At any rate, there are plenty of samples in the directory I pointed to in my answer.  One of them might be helpful to you.

Comment: I don't think so. All the examples in `win32comext/shell/demos/servers` seem to pertain to adding additional behaviors to the windows shell.

Comment: Also, `folder_view.py` is vista and 7 only (I think).

Comment: Hmm. That's too bad, sorry I can't help more.  I'll update the answer if something occurs to me.

Comment: Unsure if this is possible - if you'd show the Windows menu then how would you bind your events to each menu item?

Comment: It has to be possible, because it's done in many applications.
As for handling menu events, I don't think any of them need to be handled within the application. They're all things you'd call the windows API for anyways.